# Help me proving linearity of a function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be a set of $n$ vectors in a real vector space $V$.

Show that the following function $L:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow V$ is linear

$$L(t_1,t_2,...,t_n) = t_1v_1+t_2v_2+...+t_nv_n$$

i know that to prove a vector is linear, $T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y)$ and $T(c^*x) = c^*T(x)$. But since this is not in the form of vector + vector, I am confused...

Please help

Comment: It is meaningless to say a vector is linear. Also, I don't understand what has to be in the form vector + vector.

Comment: Let $\mathbf t = (t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n)$.  Then $L(t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_n) = L(\mathbf t)$.  So prove that $L(c\mathbf t) = cL(\mathbf t)$ and that $L(\mathbf s + \mathbf t) = L(\mathbf s) + L(\mathbf t)$, where $\mathbf s = (s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

For example, using that $V$ is a vector space, $L(t_1+s_1,...,t_n+s_n)= (t_1+s_1)v_1+...+(t_n+s_n)v_n= (t_1v_1+...+t_nv_n )+ +(s_1v_1+...s_nv_n)=L(t_1,...,t_n)+L(s_1,...,s_n).$